# How do you make it so that when you enter a number it puts a space between each integer

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, pseudocode

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Digits {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         * 
    count = 1 
    temp = n 
    while (temp > 10) 
        Increment count. 
        Divide temp by 10.0. 
   */
        
        //Assignment: fix this code to print: 1 2 3 (for 123)
        //temp = 3426 -> 3 4 2 6
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        int count = 1;
        int temp = input.nextInt();
        while(temp >= 10){
            count++;
            temp = temp / 10;
            System.out.print(temp + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

Need help fixing code.
Example: when you type 123 it becomes 1 2 3.

Comment: Try reading the input as a String, then use a loop `for (char c : temp.toCharArray())`

Comment: it says Cannot invoke toCharArray() on the primitive type int

Comment: perhaps you should change it to a `String`

Comment: `String str = "1234".replaceAll("(\\d)", "$1 ").trim();`

Answer (score 0):

Most of your code is correct, and what you are trying to do is divide by 10 and then print out the value - this probably should have been a modulus operation `%` to get the remainder of the operation and print that out - but a nice way of thinking about it.

Nevertheless.

You can just use a string and then split the string on each character

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");

        // we know that we are going to get some input - so we will just grab it as a String
        // whilst we are expecting an int - we will test this later.
        // we are doing this as it makes it easier to split the contents of a string
        String temp = input.next();

        // is this an int? - we will test this first
        try {
            // if this parsing fails - then it will throw a java.lang.NumberFormat exception 
            // see the catch block below
            int test = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            
            

            // at this point it is an int no exception was thrown- so let's go 
            // through and start printing out each character with a space after it

            // the temp(which is a string).toCharArray returns a char[] which we
            // can just iterate through and set the variable of each iteration to 'c'
            for (char c : temp.toCharArray()) {
                
                // now we are going to print out the character with a space after it
                System.out.print(c + " ");
            }

        } catch (NumberFormatException ex){
            // this is not an int as we got a number format exception...

            System.out.println("You did not enter an integer. :(");
        }

        // be nice and close the resource
        input.close();
    }
```

Comment: are you able to fix up my original code to get to the same solution?

Comment: ahhhh, no.  The code above is well commented - I will add some more comments so that you understand the logic here

Answer (score 0):

Your code is dividing by ten each time, that could be used to print the value in reverse. To print it forward you need a bit [more math](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/231745/135560) involving logarithms. Sometime like,

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
int temp = input.nextInt();
while (temp > 0) {
    int p = (int) (Math.log(temp) / Math.log(10));
    int v = (int) (temp / Math.pow(10, p));
    System.out.print(v + " ");
    temp -= v * Math.pow(10, p);
}
```

Alternatively, read a line of input. Strip out all non digits and then print every character separated by a space. Like,

```
String temp = input.nextLine().replaceAll("\\D", "");
System.out.println(temp.replaceAll("(.)", "$1 "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering solely your question, you can use this one-line code.

```
int test = 123;
System.out.println(String.join(" ", Integer.toString(test).split("")));
```

Output is: 1 2 3